# selecting closest select from checkbox when unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the value of a dropdown (select) based on whether my checkbox is checked or not. Here's the code i'm using, but it's not working:

```
    <select name="scType" class="scType" onchange="$('.all').hide();$('.'+this.value).show();" style="display:none;">
      <option value="One" selected>One</option>
      <option value="Two">Two</option>
    </select>

<span id="showActiveS" style="display:none;"><input name="showActive" class="showActive" type="checkbox" id="showActive" onclick="(this.checked)?$('.isNotActive').hide():$('.'+$(this).closest('.scType').val().show())"> Show Only Active?</span>
```

The $('.isNotActive').hide() part works, but i can't get the other part to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example shows how to output a selected value of a drop down on checkbox checked with jQuery.

HTML:

```
<select name="scType" class="scType">
  <option value="Five" selected>Five</option>
  <option value="Six">Six</option>
</select>

<select name="scType" class="scType">
  <option value="Three" selected>Three</option>
  <option value="Four">Four</option>
</select>

<select name="scType" class="scType">
  <option value="One" selected>One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
</select>

<span id="showActiveS">
<input name="showActive" class="showActive" type="checkbox" id="showActive">
Display Closest Drop Down Value
</span>

<div>Output: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.showActive').on('click', function(){ 
  if ($(this).prop('checked'))
    $('#output').text($(this).parent().prev('.scType').val());
  else 
    $('#output').empty();
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cv22hwm6/7/

Comment: not trying to change the value, just grab the existing value.... the reason i did closest is because there are 3 dropdowns on the page with the same classes and ID's (i know, but that's what it is right now). Any ideas?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot

Comment: Did this help you?